# Teradata. How to sum all values within a group?

Tags: teradata

My initial table looks like this

```
id  value
1   20
1   50
1   30
2   60 
2   5
2   35
```

I need the following resulting table

```
id  value   cum         | ( this is explanation not a field) 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ __ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ __ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ __ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
1   20      20          | (0  + 20 = 20) 
1   30      50          | (30 + 20 = 50) 
1   50      100         | (50 + 50 = 100) 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ __ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ __ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
2   5       5           | (0  + 5 = 5) 
2   35      40          | (5  + 35 = 40) 
2   60      100         | (40 + 60 = 100)
```

The logic is

1)  `ORDER` the original table `BY value ASC`

2)  `SUM` up all the previous values resulting in a cumulative `cum` field . So  the `cum` column is the `SUM` of all `value`  less than the current `value`  .

I need to do this with sql only without a stored procedure

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you describe a Cumulative Sum:

```
sum(value) 
over (partition by id 
      order by values
      rows unbounded preceding)
```

The `rows unbounded preceding` is needed in Teradata, because it defaults to `rows unbounded preceding and unbounded following` (a *Group Sum*), which is different than Standard SQL's default of `range unbounded preceding`.

Comment: `SEL  "id", "value",    SUM ( "value") OVER (PARTITION BY "id"ORDER BY "value") 
 FROM myTab   
 GROUP BY 1,2` This gives all `100`

Comment: Sorry, forgot the `rows unbounded preceding` part, fixed it.

Comment: Thank you. I used to do this using `with recursive`